# Not enough memory if using UEFI

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, uefi, ram

When attempting to install Ubuntu, Kubuntu, or really any flavour of Ubuntu 19.04, I get to the Grub prompt like normal, but the minute I choose a kernel to boot, I get the message "Not enough memory" printed on the screen.

If I press any button, I will immediately get a kernel panic and the computer locks up.

This only happens if I boot in UEFI mode, but not in MBR mode.

My computer actually has an ASUS Z170 Deluxe motherboard with 16GB of 3000MHz DDR4 memory, a Core i7-6700K, and 2 NVIDIA GTX 1080 graphics cards. It's also connected to a display via DisplayPort, as well as standard fare keyboard and mouse.

Windows boots on this machine without issues. *MacOS* boots in this machine. Ubuntu 19.04 in UEFI mode does not, and I really want to install Ubuntu 19.04 in UEFI mode, as I plan to make it my main platform.

Do you guys have any idea what's wrong? I will happily provide any further info I can find.